# Facebook .NET SDK Posting image to Facebook page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, facebook, sdk

i am using facbook .net sdk in wpf application to post an image to facebook page.

```
string photoAlbumID = <page id>;

        FacebookMediaObject facebookUploader = new FacebookMediaObject { FileName = "1.png", ContentType = "image/png" };

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)+"\\" + facebookUploader.FileName);
        facebookUploader.SetValue(bytes);

        var postInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postInfo.Add("message", "test photo");
        postInfo.Add("image", facebookUploader);
        postInfo.Add("access_token", <page tocken>);
        var fbResult = client.Post("/" + photoAlbumID + "/photos", postInfo);
        dynamic result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbResult;
```

the problem is the image is being uploaded but it is only visible by the page admin knowing that the post is public, and when i post it directly from facebook via internet browser it is visible.

Comment: This is not the official Facebook SDK, Have you tried contacting the author regarding this ? Does the page admin have to verify it or approve it ? have you checked the page settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the application was not published yet .. it was on the developer mode that makes no one can see the posts except the application admins.